# Add Dropdown Menu to NSSearchField in OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Could someone please show or explain me how to implement a dropdown menu/ filter options to `NSSearchField` in Objective-C.

My scenario is I have a `NSSearchField` and a `NSTableView` on nib. I would like to search Animals|Birds|Reptiles categories.

My `NSTableview` is connected to `NSArray` that displays these items and I have done the predicate to filter out to the corresponding search string and it all works fine.

I would like add these categories (Animals, Birds, Reptiles) next to the Magnifying glass icon on the `NSSearchField` so the user could select from it.

I did download Apple's sample of iSpend demo app but I can't figure it out how they implement it.

[image: image filter menu options]

Answer (score 3):

never mind I found the solution by adding a nsmenu to searchfield:
[Apple's Searchfield Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SearchField/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)